# Flex Builder and CMS?

Tags: flex3, content-management-system, flexbuilder

How can I implement Joomla in Flex Builder? Or is there any other CMS for Flex Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex Builder is an IDE that helps you create flex based application. Joomla is a PHP web application that runs inside a web server such as apache.

What is that you want to do with Joomla and Flex Builder?